# Opcache on php 7.0 Centos 7

Tags: nginx, centos, php-7, opcache

i ran into a problem, which is bugging me for a couple of days ... I googled all over the internet but couldn't find the answer.

I have VPS with centos 7, and seperate VPS for proxy with nginx.

Centos VPS have php7.0 but for some strange reason CLI version of PHP is 7.1.

I wanted to install Opcache (Zend) and manage to set it to work over CLI, but cant find the way to do it in browser.

I am not DevOps guy so any help here would be really great, since I dont want to spend rest of the week with that.

Oh and I did change both php.ini-s (cli and apache) setting the opcache.enable=1 and setting the path for cache files, also did tons of reboots and restarts of apache ...

And if i print out the phpinfo() I can see that ini file is parsed (    /etc/opt/remi/php70/php.d/10-opcache.ini) but there is no section with table of settings for Opcache as I saw on other documentations.

Thank you guys for help!